# Assign empty string to javascript variable

Tags: javascript

I get return value as null and assign that value it shows as null in the UI. But I want to check some condition and if it is null, it should not show up anything..
I tried the below code and it doesn't work

```js
var companyString;
if(utils.htmlEncode(item.companyname) == null)
{
  companyString = '';
}
else{
  companyString = utils.htmlEncode(item.companyname);
}
```

Comment: why don't you just do `var companyString=" "`?

Comment: You should compare `item.companyname` to null (but probably really any false-y value), not the encoded form.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Compare `item.companyname` to null (but probably really any false-y value) - and *not* the encoded form.

This is because the encoding will turn `null` to `"null"` (or perhaps `""`, which are strings) and `"null" == null` (or `any_string == null`) is false.

Using the ternary operator it can be written as so:

```
var companyString = item.companyname
  ? utils.htmlEncode(item.companyname)
  : "";
```

Or with coalescing:

```
var companyString = utils.htmlEncode(item.companyname ?? "");
```

Or in a long-hand form:

```
var companyString;
if(item.companyname) // if any truth-y value then encode
{
  companyString = utils.htmlEncode(item.companyname);
}
else{                // else, default to an empty string
  companyString = '';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var companyString;
if(item.companyname !=undefined &&   item.companyname != null ){
companyString = utils.htmlEncode(item.companyname);  
}
else{
companyString = '';
}
```

Better to check `not undefined` along with `not null` in case of javascript. And you can also put `alert` or `console.log`to check what value you are getting to check why your if block not working. Also, utls.htmlEncode will convert your `null` to String having `null literal`  , so compare without encoding.

Answer (score -1):

```
var companyString="";
if(utils.htmlEncode(item.companyname) != null)
{
   companyString = utils.htmlEncode(item.companyname);
}
```